# What's causing this unexpected behavior of the cleveref package, which occurs when I try to reference multiple things at a time?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, amsthm, debugging

I'm trying to reference two propositions together, in a document that I'm typesetting. From the `cleveref` documentation, I learned that `\cref{label1,label2}` is the correct syntax for doing so, but I'm running into trouble when I try. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,cleveref}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}

\begin{document}

\begin{prop}\label{a}
\end{prop}
\begin{prop}\label{b}
\end{prop}

\cref{a} \cref{b}\\

\cref{a,b}

\end{document}
```

The output is just fine for the single references, `\cref{a}` and `\cref{b}`, but `\cref{a,b}` produces an error message:

> cref reference format for label type `prop' undefined

I find this strange, because everything works fine for single references. Am I messing something up, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell `cleveref` what the *plural* name is:

```
\crefname{prop}{Proposition}{Propositions}
```

As a matter of good practice, you might also specify

```
\Crefname{prop}{Proposition}{Propositions}
```

so that `\Cref` and friends work as expected. Adjust as you see fit.

Here's a complete MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,cleveref}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\crefname{prop}{Proposition}{Propositions}%<--- new bit!
\Crefname{prop}{Proposition}{Propositions}%<--- new bit!
\begin{document}

\begin{prop}\label{a}
\end{prop}
\begin{prop}\label{b}
\end{prop}

\cref{a} \cref{b}

\cref{a,b}

\end{document}
```